# Sitecore Upgrade to v.8.1-U2 : Experience Editor - A serious error occurred please contact the administrator

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1, sitecore-speak-ui, experience-editor

Just wanted to check if there's anyone here already encountered the error traces below when opening the Sitecore Experience Editor.

```
22812 2016:05:06 10:36:52 ERROR Error processing command url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.ActiveItemTest error:System.InvalidOperationException: Could not retrieve request class for url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.ActiveItemTest
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.Process(HttpContext context)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

19668 2016:05:06 10:36:52 ERROR Error processing command url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.IsContentTestingEnabledRequest error:System.InvalidOperationException: Could not retrieve request class for url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.IsContentTestingEnabledRequest
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.Process(HttpContext context)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

22812 2016:05:06 10:36:52 ERROR Error processing command url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.ActiveItemTest error:System.InvalidOperationException: Could not retrieve request class for url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.ActiveItemTest
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.Process(HttpContext context)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

19668 2016:05:06 10:36:52 ERROR Error processing command url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.IsContentTestingEnabledRequest error:System.InvalidOperationException: Could not retrieve request class for url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.IsContentTestingEnabledRequest
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.Process(HttpContext context)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

19668 2016:05:06 10:36:59 ERROR Error processing command url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.ActiveItemTest error:System.InvalidOperationException: Could not retrieve request class for url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.ActiveItemTest
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.Process(HttpContext context)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
10172 2016:05:06 10:36:59 ERROR Error processing command url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.ActiveItemTest error:System.InvalidOperationException: Could not retrieve request class for url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.ActiveItemTest
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.Process(HttpContext context)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

12592 2016:05:06 10:36:59 ERROR Error processing command url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/ContentTesting.PersonalizationGallery.CanExecute error:System.InvalidOperationException: Could not retrieve request class for url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/ContentTesting.PersonalizationGallery.CanExecute
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.Process(HttpContext context)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

22424 2016:05:06 10:37:00 ERROR Error processing command url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.ItemVersions.Count error:System.InvalidOperationException: Could not retrieve request class for url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.ItemVersions.Count
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.Process(HttpContext context)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

19668 2016:05:06 10:37:00 ERROR Error processing command url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.ActiveItemTest error:System.InvalidOperationException: Could not retrieve request class for url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.ActiveItemTest
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.Process(HttpContext context)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

16160 2016:05:06 10:37:02 ERROR Error processing command url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.ActiveTests.Count error:System.InvalidOperationException: Could not retrieve request class for url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.ActiveTests.Count
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.Process(HttpContext context)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

16136 2016:05:06 10:37:03 ERROR Error processing command url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.HistoricalTests.Count error:System.InvalidOperationException: Could not retrieve request class for url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.HistoricalTests.Count
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.Process(HttpContext context)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

22812 2016:05:06 10:37:03 ERROR Error processing command url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.SuggestedTests.Count error:System.InvalidOperationException: Could not retrieve request class for url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.SuggestedTests.Count
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.Process(HttpContext context)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

22812 2016:05:06 10:37:04 ERROR Error processing command url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.ActiveItemTest error:System.InvalidOperationException: Could not retrieve request class for url:/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/Optimization.ActiveItemTest
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.Process(HttpContext context)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

I tried the workaround of reverting to SHEER UI, but I didn't do the trick.
Described here: https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/5/t/3049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, after enabling the necessary configuration related to Content Testing *\Website\App_Config\Include\ContentTesting*, the said error didn't appear anymore

In my case:

- Sitecore.ContentTesting.ApplicationDependencies.config
- Sitecore.ContentTesting.config
- Sitecore.ContentTesting.Intelligence.config
- Sitecore.ContentTesting.Mvc.config
- Sitecore.ContentTesting.Processing.Aggregation.config
- Sitecore.ContentTesting.Solr.IndexConfiguration.config

Answer (score 2):

After trying a number of these solutions our issue was that the SPEAK URLs require a particular case be used in the request.

If you're using URL Rewrite 2.x to lowercase URLs for SEO purposes, you'll need to manually add an exclusion for /-/speak/ requests.

```
<rule name="LowerCaseRule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/sitecore" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/temp" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/ScriptResource" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/WebResource" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/Shibboleth.sso" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.axd" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.asmx" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.svc" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/layouts/system" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="\?.*sc_mode" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\/-\/speak" negate="true" /><!-- SPEAK addition -->
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
</rule>
```

Based upon [Sitecore Experience Editor Issue : A serious error occurred please contact the administrator](https://codeandnuts.wordpress.com/2017/04/19/sitecore-experience-editor-issue-a-serious-error-occurred-please-contact-the-administrator/).

Answer (score 0):

The info in the link referenced in the question only spoke about updating the Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config. However, this [This KB Page](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/359871) also lists the Sitecore.MvcExperienceEditor.config to be edited. Editing both configs worked for me.